# Python3 How to get the rest array when given a whole array and a sub-array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array and a sub-array, like following:

```
import numpy as np    
total_array = np.arange(10)
sub_array = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

I was wondering how to get the `rest_array = total_array - sub_array = np.array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])`?

Any simple ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`np.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) to get the result you want

```
import numpy as np    
total_array = np.arange(10)
sub_array = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])

rest_array = np.setdiff1d(total_array, sub_array)
rest_array

array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```